# How to have included/required scripts use local files

Tags: php, include

My situation: I have a class that I want to use in a number of places, so I placed it high in the directory tree:

```
/www/libs/classA/classA.php
```

It uses a config file located in the same directory called `config.ini` and references it locally in the constructor. However, when I include it from a script in a different directory, it tries to load the config file from the directory the calling script is in. Is there any way I can look in the directory the included file is in? Ideally I could move the script to a different directory and not make any changes to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the absolute path when including/loading files. And you can retrieve that absolute path with the [`__FILE__` constant](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and [`dirname` function](http://docs.php.net/dirname):

```
dirname(__FILE__).'/config.ini'
```

This will five you the absolute path of the `config.ini` file in the same directory the currently executed script file is located in. So when that code is executed in your `classA.php` script file, you would get `/www/libs/classA/config.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include/require a file from the current file's directory if you have no path info in the argument, e.g. include('file2.php');.  But I think even if you have './file2.php'), then it's going to become relative to the directory of the first-included/executed script.

I like the dirname(____FILE____)... method, but I believe in the case where a certain set of files is intended to always be deployed in the same directory, the direct file include promotes cohesion.